# Is it possible to create a log file in the terminal in python?

Tags: python, file, logging, terminal

I have a Python program that takes about three voltage readings per second. I normally run it from the Linux desktop Lxterminal. Then later the voltages vs time are used in Pylab to create a plot. However as it takes voltage readings it sometimes will pause, which creates gaps in the data, which can ruin the test. These gaps last from 1 to 6 seconds. I noticed the pauses are caused by my program's 'print >> logfile, time(), (volts)' script. But if I remove the logfile script and run it from the command prompt (aka "the terminal", "the console", "the shell") these pauses are not there. 
    When I run program from the command prompt it prints out a long series of voltages that show up on the monitor, but there is no log file to use to create a plot. My question is, is there a way to store these voltages in the terminal shell and then use these nice no-gaps voltages later on in Pylab? I tried:

```
 list = time(), volts
```

But I don't know what to do next or if I'm even heading in the right direction. Here is my program.

```
import time, sys, signal, math    
from Adafruit_ADS1x15 import ADS1x15    
from time import time, sleep    
def signal_handler(signal, frame):    
    sys.exit(0)    
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)    
ADS1115 = 0x01    
adc = ADS1x15(ic=ADS1115)    

while True:    
   voltsdiff = adc.readADCDifferential01(4096, 8)    
   logfile = open('logfile.txt', 'a')    
   print >> logfile, time(), voltsdiff    
   logfile.close()    
   sleep(0.25)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `logging` module

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug(yourdataToSaveInFile)
```

No need to open and close your file every loop iteration.

```
with open('logfile.txt', 'a') as f:
    while True:    
       voltsdiff = adc.readADCDifferential01(4096, 8)    
       print >> f, time(), voltsdiff    
       sleep(0.25)
```

Comment: There's a python module for everything :')

Comment: Well, logging.basicConfig doesn't work either. It has the same data gaps that my print>>logfile does. Is what is being shown on the monitor stored anywhere? Is my little Raspberry Pi computer simply not up to the job?

Comment: import time, sys, signal, math

Comment: My program is now posted above.

Comment: Your dead-on jramirez! That fixed it!